# How to style Checkbox Border color within a ComboBox.ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a problem to change the `BorderBrush` color for the `CheckBox` on an `IsMouseOver` Trigger within a ComboBox.ItemTemplate.

I have following layout:

[Layout before changing ControlTemplate for CheckBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edVgL.png)

I can set the BorderBrush directly and it works (red), but as soon as I change the ControlTemplate for the CheckBox (BorderBrush), the CheckBox disappears on the left site:

[CheckBox disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGbis.png)

The strange thing is, I can modify for sample the BorderThickness property and it works and the Checkbox does not disappear.

Here is my Code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Controls.MultiSelectComboBoxControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Border 
                        Name="Border"
                        Padding="2">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#DDD"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <!--<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Border Name="Border"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGreen"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>-->
</UserControl.Resources>

<ComboBox 
    x:Name="MultiSelectCombo"   
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
    OverridesDefaultStyle="True" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Title}" 
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      Tag="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}" 
                      Click="CheckBox_Click"
                      BorderBrush="Red"
                      VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ComboBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Grid>
                <ToggleButton  
                    x:Name="ToggleButton"  
                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                    Focusable="false"                            
                    ClickMode="Press" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                    <ToggleButton.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Border 
                                    x:Name="Border"  
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                    CornerRadius="2" 
                                    Background="White" 
                                    BorderBrush="#eaeaea"
                                    BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" />
                                <Border  
                                    x:Name="BorderComp"  
                                    Grid.Column="0" 
                                    CornerRadius="2"  
                                    Margin="1"  
                                    Background="White" 
                                    BorderBrush="Black" 
                                    BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" >
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"  
                                           Background="White" Padding="3" />
                                </Border>
                                <Path  
                                    x:Name="Arrow" 
                                    Grid.Column="1"      
                                    Fill="Black" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                    Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ToggleButton.Template>
                </ToggleButton>
                <Popup  
                    Name="Popup" 
                    Placement="Bottom"                         
                    AllowsTransparency="True"  
                    Focusable="False"  IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" 
                    PopupAnimation="Slide">
                    <Grid  
                        Name="DropDown" 
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"   
                        MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" 
                        MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                        <Border  
                            x:Name="DropDownBorder"  
                            BorderThickness="1" Background="White" 
                            BorderBrush="#eaeaea"/>
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" DataContext="{Binding}">
                            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                    <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ComboBox.Template>
</ComboBox>
```

How can I solve this problem???

Comment: `BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}"` - why Background is used here?

Comment: ohh this is a mistake of several test cases, it should be `BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"`